# Oque é esse erro ? DisconnectedContext

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Galera blz ?

Estou aqui programando para Windows Form com a linguagem C#
quando me deparo com um erro  "DisconnectedContext" .

Bom deixa eu explicar como funciona meu programa,  tenho vários forms em um projeto, onde eu tenho que fazer a transição entres esses forms, por exemplo um form é o de Login já o outro é Um "Plano de aula" por exemplo.

Na transição do form "Login" para o Form "Plano de Aula" no Construtor de "Plano de Aula" eu recebo essa exceção.

Basicamente a instrução é o seguinte , quando eu clico no botão logar o sistema faz a autenticação do professor, logo após se tudo dê certo (Professor autenticado), passo uma instrução onde instancio uma thread e passo um método nela, para poder fechar o Form "Login" para a abertura do outro form "Plano de Aula".

Segue a foto : [image: http://i.imgur.com/6WWnRn8.jpg]

Segue abaixo os códigos :

**1 - Clicando botão logar**

```
    private void Btn_Entrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string login = txbLogin.Text;
        string senha = txbSenha.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(senha))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não pode haver campo(s) vazio(s)");
            return;
        }


        if (login.Contains("'"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não é permitido usar caracteres no login");
            return;
        }
        if (senha.Contains("'"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não é permitido usar caracteres '  na senha");
            return;


        }



         professor = new Professor();


        if ((professor.Codigo = professor.autenticarProfessor(login, senha))                   != null)
        {
            professor.bindProfessor(login, professor);    

            this.Close(); //Fecho esta tela
            this.Dispose(); //Dispose nela
            th = new Thread(abrirTela_Plano_Aula); //Abro uma nova linha de 
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
        }
        else {

            MessageBox.Show("Dados incorretos");
            return;
        }
    }
```

**2 - Método que abre o outro form**

```
    private void abrirTela_Plano_Aula()
    {
        Application.Run(new Plano_Aula(professor)); //Aqui chamo a nova tela

    }
```

**3 - Construtor Plano de Aula** 
*Aqui faço verificações se o professor tem foto
 se ele não tiver,  eu vou no banco e busco uma foto para professores sem foto*

```
    public Plano_Aula(Professor professor)
    {
        this.professor = professor;
        InitializeComponent();
        //Foto professor logado
        imgProfessor.ImageLocation = professor.FotoProfessor;
        imgProfessor.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(professor.FotoProfessor))
        {
            if (professor.Sexo == "M")
            {
                professor.FotoProfessor = new ConfigurarImagemSistema().getImg("fotoAlunoDesconhecido", "M", "chamada");
                imgProfessor.ImageLocation = professor.FotoProfessor;

            }
            else if (professor.Sexo == "F")
            {
                professor.FotoProfessor = new     ConfigurarImagemSistema().getImg("fotoAlunaDesconhecido", "F", "chamada");
                imgProfessor.ImageLocation = professor.FotoProfessor;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Esta exceção ocorre quando você executa o programa fora do Visual Studio? E quando você executa fora do depurador?

Comment: Dentro do visual studio.